# Building Jersey web services executable

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I have developed Jersey web services for the first time. Right now I am running my services on my pc only using eclipse. How can I Make executable file for services so that I can install it on other servers also?

Thanks in advance for you kind replies.

Answer (score 2):

well, web applications dont work like that! In java (an similar to other thechologies) you usually package compiled code using either jar, war, or ear. Then you have to install those files (e.g. myapp.war) into another webserver such as tomcat, glassfish, jboss or the like